QGIS-Plugin: How to re-integrate QDialogButtonBox after deleting the buttons?
I'm writing a plugin for QGIS and created the basic-code according to this: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/building_a_python_plugin.html, so the base code is like this: https://github.com/g-sherman/Qgis-Plugin-Builder/blob/master/plugin_templates/toolbutton_with_dialog/template/module_name.tmpl#L195
Unfortunately I deleted the buttons when I started as I wanted to start 'fresh' and when I now add the QDialogButtonBox in QT-Designer, it doesn't work anymore.
What do I need to do to configure the buttons in the QDialogButtonBox, so that they work again? In other words: which code in the plugin base-code do I need to check and adapt so that this part works again:
        if result:
            # Write here your code which should run when you hit the button 'OK'
            print('test)

Do I need to create a button and if so, with which widget and how do I integrate it into the code?
What do I need to change, so that it prints 'test' on the console?

Usually your base plugin will have an OK and Cancel button already defined. How did you construct your plugin

I think I did it with this tutorial, but deleted the buttons to start fresh (I guess): https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/building_a_python_plugin.html.
How can I re-enter those buttons?

the qt designer in the same way as all the other elements in your dialog

ok, so the code above won't work anymore, right?

the code above will work assuming that howwever you dialog closes it returns true or false. However if you have nothing in your dialog you should probably just start again

I have already a lot in that plugin, so I cannot start all over again. But there must be a way to make this work again, and I guess, it must have to do with adding again QDialogButtonBox and configure it. But how do I do it?

Thank you, I had a look into it, but the relevant stuff (as in 'connections') I cannot find in the qt designer, so I assume, that I have to set this in the code. Where in the QT designer you can set the configurations for the connections? I could just integrate a normal button with ok and cancel, but I would like the code in the plugin as is.

Btw - this also happens if you rename the button box

To restore your button box to original state, open your plugin dialog .ui file in QtDesigner and drag in a Dialog Button Box (make it part of the dialog layout). At the bottom right there is a Signal/Slot Editor tab. Click on it. Use the green plus icon to add connections. Double click each row under sender, signal, receiver & slot to edit. Set your connections like the image below (TestPluginDialogBase will instead be the object name of your dialog).


Thank you very, very much! This worked!
